# pointer to an array, GCC

Tags: arrays, pointers

the ggc gives me this error, and i can not believe that the error is correct as both of input and expected argument are [8][8] pointer to an array, any idea what is wrong here!

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:main.c:24:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘DRESC_Transform’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from main.c:1:0:
global.h:13:6: note: expected ‘short int * (*)[8]’ but argument is of type ‘short int (*)[8][8]’
```

this is global.h

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

# define ROW 8
# define COL 8
# define SHIFT_AMOUNT 16
# define SHIFT_MASKT ( 1<<SHIFT_AMOUNT )-1


void DRESC_Transform( short *matrix [ROW][COL]);


void DRESC_Transform( short *matrix [ROW][COL]){


  int _tmp_matrix [ROW*COL]; // 2KB REGISTER 

  for ( unsigned i = 0; i <ROW; i++){ 

    int _tmp0, _tmp1, _tmp2, _tmp3, _tmp4, _tmp5, _tmp6, _tmp7;

    _tmp0 = *matrix [i][0];
    _tmp1 = *matrix [i][1];
    _tmp2 = *matrix [i][2];
    _tmp3 = *matrix [i][3];
    _tmp4 = *matrix [i][4];
    _tmp5 = *matrix [i][5];
    _tmp6 = *matrix [i][6];
    _tmp7 = *matrix [i][7];

    _tmp_matrix [    (i<<3)] = _tmp0 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp_matrix [1 + (i<<3)] = _tmp1 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp_matrix [2 + (i<<3)] = _tmp2 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp_matrix [3 + (i<<3)] = _tmp3 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp_matrix [4 + (i<<3)] = _tmp4 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp_matrix [5 + (i<<3)] = _tmp5 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp_matrix [6 + (i<<3)] = _tmp6 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp_matrix [7 + (i<<3)] = _tmp7 <<SHIFT_AMOUNT;

  }

  for ( unsigned i = 0; i < ROW; i++){ // a row calculation

    int _tmp;

    _tmp_matrix[    (i<<3)] = ( _tmp_matrix[    (i<<3)] + _tmp_matrix[1 + (i<<3)] ) >>1;
    _tmp                    = ( _tmp_matrix[    (i<<3)] - _tmp_matrix[1 + (i<<3)] );
    _tmp_matrix[1 + (i<<3)] = ( _tmp_matrix[2 + (i<<3)] + _tmp_matrix[3 + (i<<3)] ) >>1;
    _tmp_matrix[2 + (i<<3)] = ( _tmp_matrix[4 + (i<<3)] + _tmp_matrix[5 + (i<<3)] ) >>1;
    _tmp_matrix[4 + (i<<3)] =   _tmp;
    _tmp                    = ( _tmp_matrix[6 + (i<<3)] + _tmp_matrix[7 + (i<<3)] ) >>1;
    _tmp_matrix[6 + (i<<3)] = ( _tmp_matrix[2 + (i<<3)] - _tmp_matrix[5 + (i<<3)] );
    _tmp_matrix[5 + (i<<3)] = ( _tmp_matrix[1 + (i<<3)] - _tmp_matrix[3 + (i<<3)] );
    _tmp_matrix[3 + (i<<3)] =   _tmp;
    _tmp_matrix[7 + (i<<3)] = ( _tmp_matrix[3 + (i<<3)] - _tmp_matrix[7 + (i<<3)] );
  }


  for ( unsigned i = 0; i <ROW; i++){

    int _tmp0, _tmp1, _tmp2, _tmp3, _tmp4, _tmp5, _tmp6, _tmp7;

    _tmp0 = _tmp_matrix [    (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp1 = _tmp_matrix [1 + (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp2 = _tmp_matrix [2 + (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp3 = _tmp_matrix [3 + (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp4 = _tmp_matrix [4 + (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp5 = _tmp_matrix [5 + (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp6 = _tmp_matrix [6 + (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;
    _tmp7 = _tmp_matrix [7 + (i<<3)] >>SHIFT_AMOUNT;

    *matrix [i][0] = _tmp0;
    *matrix [i][1] = _tmp1;
    *matrix [i][2] = _tmp2;
    *matrix [i][3] = _tmp3;
    *matrix [i][4] = _tmp4;
    *matrix [i][5] = _tmp5;
    *matrix [i][6] = _tmp6;
    *matrix [i][7] = _tmp7;


  } 

}
```

and this is the main:

```
#include "global.h"

void main (){

  short matrix [ROW][COL] = {{7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2}, // <<<<---
                 {7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2},
                 {7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2},
                 {7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2},
                 {7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2},
                 {7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2},
                 {7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2},
                 {7, 1, 6, 6, 3, -5, 4, 2}};

  DRESC_Transform(&matrix); // <<<---

  printf("the transformed matrix is \n");
  printf("{");
  for ( unsigned i; i <ROW; i++){
    for ( unsigned j = 0; j <COL; j++){
      printf( "%d,", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\b}, \n");
  }
  printf("\b} \n");

}
```

Comment: In case you didn't know, `1 + i<<3` is `(1 + i)<<3`, not `1 + (i<<3)`.

Comment: wow, thank you, i didn't notice that the replace-all function, removed that!

Comment: And FYI the problem is that the function expects a two-dimensional array of `short*` but you pass it a two-dimensional array of `short`.

Comment: the function got the address of an Array stored in memory, i think it had to be OK, as the expected argument of the function is also a pointer.
if you wanna change the value of an array without putting that in the output of the function, how would you do that?

Comment: I posted an answer, see if that clarifies anything.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for arrays of any dimension:

```
T array[S1][S2][...][SN]
```

when you pass it to a function, decays to

```
T array[][S2][...][SN]
```

which is nothing more than a different syntax for

```
T (*array)[S2][...][SN]
```

Therefore, if you want to pass the array `short matrix[ROW][COL]` to a function, the function should accept `short matrix[][COL]`.

As you can see by the syntax `T (*array)[S2][...][SN]`, arrays are passed as pointers. So have no fear; if you modify the elements of the array inside the function, the result will be visible in the original array when that function returns.

The only time you wouldn't be able to see an assignment is if you modify the pointer `matrix`, which is a local variable in the function, and directly assign it to point to a new array, like `matrix = ...`.

---

As for other notes, `void main` isn't a valid declaration of `main`. It should be `int main`, and if you're using C, you should have `return 0` at the end.

Comment: hi , thank you for your response .... my idea was the same, i thought i give the function the address of the array so it can change the value of array in the memory! but to be honest i don't understand what do you mean with array[S1][S2][...][SN] decays to array[][S2][...][SN] and that these are the same as (*array)[S2][...][SN] as we pass it to a function!!

Comment: @inman you can only change the values in the array. And if you do it like I showed, it will do that. And when I said the T array[S1][S2] thing meant that, for example, if you declare a variable int array[1][2][3] and you want to pass it to a function, you should write the function to take either an int array[][2][3] or int (*array)[2][3]. Between those two, you can pick which one you like more since they are the same.